# Favorite system in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Image

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".like").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("heart");
 });
});
```

```css
.like {
  padding-right: 6px;
  color: #00000030;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  animation: like 0.5s linear;
}

.heart {
  color: #FF0000;
  animation: heart 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
{% for m in musicl %}
  <div class="card">
        <div class="top">
          <div class="year">{{m.Year}}</div>
          <span class="like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>
        </div>

        <div class="middle">
          <a href="https://google.com" id="link" target="_blank">
            <div class="img-container"><img src="{{ m.Image.url }}"></div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <a href="https://google.com" id="link" target="_blank">
          <div class="bottom">
            <div class="title">{{m.Name}}</div>
            <div class="genre">{{m.Genre}}</div>
          </div>
        </a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Music(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    Year = models.IntegerField(('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    Genre = MultiSelectField(choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    Image = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, template_name='main/home.html', context={"musicl": Music.objects.all})


def wishlist(request, id):
    pass
```

How do I connect the User model to this favorite system and keep track of the favorite list in a view function(wishlist), in other words when someone clicks on the fav icon, I want that specific card to be saved to the wishlist view corresponding to that User model

Comment: Read the docs: [docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 3):

To connect your UserModel with Frontend we need to push the data (music_id) from UI to backend.

If you want to do this with django-template then you can use django-forms.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

However it you want to go on some event based such as click, following are steps...

to do this there are couple of things required.

1. Wishlist additional model required to store wishlist music
2. views.py to verify input and save wishlist
3. url-dispatcher url -> views(your bussiness logic) -> models(save data, wishlist in your case)
4. post-call to django-backend (using ajax, since you want to use store data on icon click)

**1. Model Definition**

```
class Music(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    Year = models.IntegerField(('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    Genre = MultiSelectField(choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    Image = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class WishlistMusic(models.Model):
    ## this can be depend on your choice eg (user_id, guest_id etc)
    some_id = models.IntegerField(('some_id'))
    ## relation to Music
    music = models.ForeignKey(Music, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

**2. views.py**

```
from music.models import Music, WishlistMusic
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def wishlist(request):
    music_id = request.POST.get('music_id')
    if not music_id:
        raise ValueError("Required music_id to set wishlist")
    ## can be set user id once authentication is set
    ##some_id = request.user.pk
    some_id = 3 ## Say
    try:
        music = Music.objects.get(pk=music_id)
        wishlist_obj = {
            'some_id': some_id,
            'music': music
        }
        WishlistMusic(**wishlist_obj).save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        ## Your action
        ## raise or Return HTTP response with failure status_code
        return HttpResponse('Some error occured, unable to add to wishlist') ## or can set for render
        
    return HttpResponse('Added to wishlist') ## or can set for render
```

@csrf_exempt used because we are going to POST call using ajax, django-provide Cross Site Request Forgery protection, however its not recommended to use @csrf_exempt in production environment.
more details on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/

**3. URL-Dispatcher/Path**
here we have model and views under music app so below urls.py for redirect /music url to music app url

for refr. my proj structure as
[image]

proj_name -> music_track

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from music import urls as music_urls    

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('music/', include(music_urls)),
]
```

music/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from music import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('mymusic/', views.home),  ## IP:PORT/mymusic your homepage
    path('wishlist/', views.wishlist),  ## IP:PORT/mymusic your post api to save wishlist
]
```

**4. POST API call from front-end to django.**

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".like").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("heart");
        var pk = $(this).find('input[id="abc"]').val();
        var data = {
            'music_id': pk
            };
        $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: '../wishlist/',
                     data: data,
                     success: function(json) {
                         alert(json); // your actions after save, you can just pop-up some ui element that added to wishlist
                     }
                 })
    });
});
```

I just added one ui element (inside like class span) in html to hold the primary key of music which is required to add wishlist in model since we set music_id set as foreign key in WishlistMusic model.

.html

```
........
<a href="https://google.com" id="link" target="_blank">
          <div class="bottom">
            <div class="title" id="title">{{m.Name}}</div>
            <div class="genre" id="genre">{{m.Genre}}</div>
          </div>
          
        </a>
         <span class="like" id="abc"><input type="hidden", id="abc", value="{{m.pk}}"/>aa<i class="fa fa-heart"></i></span>
 .......
```

Following are the references you can go through for further details

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/

Answer (score 0):

I think best you can do is to manually create a new row in the music object in a script like this, and put that behind the JavaScript click event:

```
from app.models import Music

Music.objects.create(Name=name_variable, Year=year_variable, Genre=genre_variable, Image=image_variable)
Music.save()
```

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly, could you be more descriptive, please?